# iTunes Match songs grayed out

Tags: itunes, itunes-match

For no reason, my iTunes Match songs stored in the cloud are grayed out and I'm not able to play them. What may be causing this problem?

This is happening on a MacBook Air running OS X 1.8.2 and iTunes 10.7

Comment: Has iTunes Match ever worked in the past using this machine? Is the Machine iTunes Authorized for your account? Etc. Give us a bit more.

Comment: The computer worked in the past with this music and it's authorized to use the account.

Comment: Another piece of information, I have another device (an iPad) using the same iTunes Match account and it works fine.

Comment: Given that it's an annual subscription fee, and the service has been available a bit more than a year, do you need to manually resubscribe maybe because it doesn't automatically extend, or your payment option doesn't include recurring payments?

Comment: Here are some troubleshooting instructions, have you looked at these: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4054?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: The troubleshooting instructions don't say anything about songs being grayed out. UPDATE: Today the songs came back to normal. I am able to play them. I didn't have to do anything, they just went back to normal. So why were they grayed out for almost a week?